# boost::multi_array index to memory offset conversion

Tags: c++, boost

I have three-dimensional `boost::multi_array` object. I would like to convert an absolute offset from the `origin` to a multi-dimensional index and vice versa. Is there an easy way to do so using boost's built-in facilities, or I need to compute it myself given the array's shape and strides?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use some library facility.

For the offset, you can easily use pointer arithmetics¹:

```
size_t offset = &ma[1][2][3] - ma.data();
std::cout << "Offset of ma[1][2][3]: " << offset << "\n";
```

The documentation divulges a more elaborate way to get the element address: [link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/multi_array/doc/reference.html#idp18501744)

> ```
> This expression accesses a specific element of a.index_list is the unique set of indices that address the element returned. It is equivalent to the following code (disregarding intermediate temporaries): 
>     // multiply indices by strides
>     std::transform(index_list.begin(), index_list.end(),
>     a.strides(), tmp.begin(), std::multiplies<index>()),
>
>     // add the sum of the products to the origin
>     *std::accumulate(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), a.origin());
> ```

The inverse less simple. I couldn't find a direct way.

¹ note: use `std::addressof` to guard against elements overload `operator&` in generic code

Comment: I expected something like MATLAB's `ind2sub` and `sub2ind` functions, which are hidden somewhere. But it seems my expectations were too high :)